# Gmail Client for android doesn't apply my css style to email

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I'm creating a newsletter, in iOS phone it's OK, but in gmail view the style of `p` is ignored. Can you help me to resolve this problem?`

```
 <tr>
   <td >
     <table width="100%">
       <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center; align:center">
           <p style="margin 0; display:inline-block; font-size: 0.6em; font-family: Arial, sans serif; color:#999999; padding: 5px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #959595;">
             <b>Se desideri contattarci puoi scriverci a
               <a href="mailto:digitallieracphyto@alesgroupe.it" target="_blank" style="color:#818181;">
                          digitallieracphyto@alesgroupe.it
               </a><br>
             </b>
             Se ricevi questa email è perchè hai eseguito la registrazione sul nostro sito o tramite uno dei nostri servizi e hai dato il consenso a ricevere comunicazioni email da parte nostra.
             Se non desideri ricevere più la newsletter o comunicazioni da parte di Lierac clicca sui link in fondo per <a href="#" style="color: #959595">disiscriverti</a>.
           </p>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have committed an error in style attribute!

Change this:

```
<p style="margin 0; display:inline-block; font-size: 0.6em; font-family: Arial, sans serif; color:#999999; padding: 5px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #959595;">
```

with this:

```
<p style="margin: 0; display:inline-block; font-size: 0.6em; font-family: Arial, sans serif; color:#999999; padding: 5px; line-height: 1.2em; color: #959595;">
```

you forgot the two points at the margin!